# parsing XML in python 3

Tags: json, xml, mongodb, python-3.x, parsing

I have big XML files which i need to parse, convert into json and store it in mongodb.

The XML looks like this:

```
Headers
 <response>
    <tag1>sssss</tag1>
    <tag2>kkkkkk</tag2>
    <tag3>aaaaaa</tag3> 
 </response>
Footers
```

I need only the text between the two `response` tags. The problem occurs when I try to parse it. The code looks like this:

```
import pymysql
import re
import json
import xmltodict
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Open Database Connection.
db = pymysql.connect("hjj","fnddd","feoifh","fdfsddfs")

# prepare a cursor object
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL query 
cursor.execute("SQL Query")

# Fetch all rows
data = cursor.fetchall()

a = (r'(?=<response>)(.*)(?<=</response>)')
def cleanxml(xml):
    file = re.findall(a, xml, re.DOTALL)
    return file
data = list(data)
for row in data:
    thexml = cleanxml(row[-1])
    jsonString = json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(thexml), indent = 4) #error here
```

The above code gives me an error: `a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'`

I tried to convert the list(thexml) into str like so:

```
thexml = ','.join(str(x) for x in thexml)
```

Parsing after this also doesn't work:

```
xmltodict.parse(thexml) #no element found: line 1, column 0
```

How can I do this? Any help appreciated.Thanks.

I solved the above problem only to get into another. The code with the solution to the above problem:

```
a = (r'(?=<response>)(.*)(?<=</response>)')
def cleanxml(xml):
    if re.findall(a, xml, re.S):
        file = re.findall(a, xml, re.S)[0]
    else:
        file = "<response>NA</response>"
    return file
data = list(data)

for row in data:
    thexml  = cleanxml(row[1])
    jsonString = json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(thexml), indent = 4)
    d = json.loads(jsonString)
    newdict = {"caseid" : row[0]}
    newdict.update(d)
    jsondata = json.dumps(newdict, indent = 3)
```

Now, the problem I am facing is how to insert this into mongodb. I tried with the following code but it did not work and I have no clue how to solve this:

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.lexnex
collection = db['userdata']
collection.insert(newdict)
```

I get

```
 DeprecationWarning: insert is deprecated. Use insert_one or insert_many instead.
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.
```

When I try to insert it using a loop, I still get an error as it should be a SON object etc. Anyone help? The exact error: `document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping`

Comment: That data is not valid XML. XML requires that there's element (`<tag>`) at top level (i.e. whole document is enclosed in `<tag>...</tag>`).

Comment: and hence the `cleanxml` function.

Comment: While a good idea, "No element found" suggests your `cleanxml` function does not work. What if you print out its result? Does it match your expectation?

Comment: yes, exactly it does perfectly. Heres a part of it:`<response><Header><TransactionId>66215947R1376304</TransactionId>
 <Status>0</Status>
</Header>
<RecordCount>1</RecordCount><Records>`

Comment: Give xml content in proper format

Comment: @Rachit why do you need the xml? I have already parsed and cleaned it. I just need to convert it into json. Its a big nested XML and confidential too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyparsing to carve out bits from poorly-formatted XML, by defining just the part you are interested in, and then use searchString or scanString to find those bits, while skipping over the unwanted junk:

```
import pyparsing as pp

uglyxml = """
Headers
 <response>
    <tag1>sssss</tag1>
    <tag2>kkkkkk</tag2>
    <tag3>aaaaaa</tag3> 
 </response>
Footers
"""

# define pyparsing expressions for starting and ending tags
# (suppress them because the tags themselves aren't interesting,
# just the content between the tags)
t1, t1_end = map(pp.Suppress, pp.makeXMLTags('tag1'))
t2, t2_end = map(pp.Suppress, pp.makeXMLTags('tag2'))
t3, t3_end = map(pp.Suppress, pp.makeXMLTags('tag3'))
resp, resp_end = map(pp.Suppress, pp.makeXMLTags('response'))

parser = (resp 
            + t1 + pp.SkipTo(t1_end)('tag1') + t1_end 
            + t2 + pp.SkipTo(t2_end)('tag2') + t2_end 
            + t3 + pp.SkipTo(t3_end)('tag3') + t3_end
          + resp_end)

# use searchString to skip over unwanted stuff in input string
parsed_responses = parser.searchString(uglyxml)

# dump out the parsed structure
print(parsed_responses[0].dump())

# convert to a nested dict
print(parsed_responses[0].asDict())

# access the `tag1` result using object attribute form
t1 = parsed_responses[0].tag1

# print matched values by tag name - pyparsing's parsed results
# can work as mappings for str.format
print("tag1={tag1!r}, tag2={tag2!r}, tag3={tag3!r}".format(**parsed_responses[0]))

import json
print("as JSON:")
print(json.dumps(parsed_responses[0].asDict()))
```

Prints:

```
['sssss', 'kkkkkk', 'aaaaaa']
- tag1: 'sssss'
- tag2: 'kkkkkk'
- tag3: 'aaaaaa'
{'tag1': 'sssss', 'tag3': 'aaaaaa', 'tag2': 'kkkkkk'}
tag1='sssss', tag2='kkkkkk', tag3='aaaaaa'

as JSON:
{"tag2": "kkkkkk", "tag1": "sssss", "tag3": "aaaaaa"}
```

Comment: Its a big xml with plenty of tags. My problem is not extracting the useful bits. I have already done it. My problem is to convert it into json.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, change

```
xmltodict.parse(thexml)
```

to

```
[xmltodict.parse(response) for response in thexml]
```

Comment: It works but am I getting `OrderedDict` before every element? Sample Result: `[OrderedDict([('response',
               OrderedDict([('Individual',
                             OrderedDict([('PhonesPluses',
                                           OrderedDict([('PhonesPlus',
                                                         OrderedDict([('Address',
                                                                       OrderedDict([('StreetName',
                                                                                     'BELLEZZA')`

Comment: and how do I convert this into json?

Comment: Presumably xmltodict.parse() returns its result as an OrderedDict, a subclass of dict. If you're seeing that, you must be looking at the result of the list comprehension rather than passing it to json.dumps(), so it sounds like you haven't done what I said.

Comment: Never mind I got it anyway, I had another issue with ref. to the same problem. Should I post another question with my updated code?

Comment: I don't think so. If the other issue is not pertinent to the question you initially asked, then you should maybe just add an erratum to the bottom of your original post.